# I need help getting this "For" loop and "If" statement to work

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

The entire script relies on two combinations of a For loop and an If statement. Both are essentially the same. But for some reason I can get the first section to work but not the second section.

I have included my script below with notes. Thank you.

```
/** @OnlyCurrentDoc */

function onEdit(e) {

//This part ensures the main script only runs if the cell F6 in the sheet "Daily Data" is edited.
  if (
    e.source.getSheetName() == "Daily Data" &&
    e.range.columnStart == 6 &&
    e.range.columnEnd == 6 &&
    e.range.rowStart >= 6 &&
    e.range.rowEnd <= 6 
  ) {

    //Section 1: This section finds the lowest # from a list of numbers by finding the lowest empty cell in column D using an If statement:
      var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
      var daily_data = spreadsheet.getSheetByName("Daily Data");
      var entirelistoftimes = daily_data.getRange(3, 4, 62).getValues();  
          for(var i=0; i<entirelistoftimes.length ; i++){  //This For loop will run through the entire D column in sheet "Daily Data".
            if (entirelistoftimes[i] == ""){        //This If statement will look for the first empty cell.
              //Copies the Total Number:
              var TotalNo = daily_data.getRange(i+2, 2).getValues();   //Gets the # from the cell next to the last filled cell in column D.
                spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Daily Data'), true);
              spreadsheet.getRange('F8').setValues(TotalNo);  //Displays the # in a cell F8 in sheet "Daily Data".
            //Stop once the first blank cell has been found:
            break;
          }
        }

    //THIS IS THE SECTION I CANNOT GET TO WORK:
    //Section 2: This section uses the # we got from the above section to find a time from a the corresponding row of sheet "Long Term Data":
      var LTD_data = spreadsheet.getSheetByName("Long Term Data");
      var LTD_data_entirelistoftimes = LTD_data.getRange(6, 2, 65).getValues();  
          for(var j=0; j<LTD_data_entirelistoftimes.length ; j++){  //This For loop will run through the Long Term Data sheet, through the list of numbers column.
            if (LTD_data_entirelistoftimes[j] == TotalNo){        //This if statement will look through column B from row 6 for the # we got from section 1 above.
              //Copies the time from column D in Lon:
              var YesterdayTime = LTD_data.getRange(j, 4).getValues();    //Gets the time from column D in row j in the "Long Term Data" Sheet.
                spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Daily Data'), true);
                spreadsheet.getRange('F9').setValues(YesterdayTime);  //Displays the time from the time underneath the # in sheet "Daily Data".
            //Stop once the above has been completed:
            break;
          }
        }
      }
}
;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your script is modified, how about the following modification?

### Modification point:

- In your script, at `if (LTD_data_entirelistoftimes[j] == TotalNo){`, `LTD_data_entirelistoftimes[j]` and `TotalNo` are 1 dimensional array and 2 dimensional array, respectively. Because `getValues()` returns 2 dimensional array. I think that the reason of your issue is to directly compare those values.

### Modified script:

Please modify your script as follows.

#### Pattern 1:

When `==` is used for the comparison operator, you can modify as follows.

From:

```
if (LTD_data_entirelistoftimes[j] == TotalNo){
```

To:

```
if (LTD_data_entirelistoftimes[j] == TotalNo[0][0]){
```

or

```
if (LTD_data_entirelistoftimes[j][0] == TotalNo[0][0]){
```

#### Pattern 2:

When `===` is used for the comparison operator, you can modify as follows.

From:

```
if (LTD_data_entirelistoftimes[j] == TotalNo){
```

To:

```
if (LTD_data_entirelistoftimes[j][0] === TotalNo[0][0]){
```

### Note:

- At `if (entirelistoftimes[i] == ""){`, `==` is used as the comparison operator. So the if statement works.

### References:

- [getValues()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getvalues)
- [Comparison operators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators)

If this modification didn't resolve your issue, I apologize. At that time, can you provide a sample Spreadsheet? By this, I would like to modify it.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you :)

Comment: @Nagaram92 Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved.